# How to connect from container in Azure Container Instances to an internal IP of VM in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I am trying to work with Azure Container Instances. I have successfully deployed a container, but I am not managing to make it communicate with an internal IP of an instance I have deployed in Azure.
The container receives an internal IP address (as an environment variable) and is trying to connect. I can see in the logs that it doesn't manage to open the connection.
Networking policy (on the target VM and Subnet) allows connectivity to this port.

How can I troubleshoot it? Which subnet is the ACI-hosted container deployed in? I created it without public IP (as it only needs to connect to internal services).

L

Answer (score 2):

It seems that now [Azure does support it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet).

> Azure Virtual Network provides secure, private networking for your
> Azure and on-premises resources. By deploying container groups into an
> Azure virtual network, your containers can communicate securely with
> other resources in the virtual network.

For example:

```
az container create \
  --name appcontainer \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld \
  --vnet aci-vnet \
  --vnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet aci-subnet \
  --subnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Container Instances cannot (at the time of writing) connect to Vnet (and everything in it) internally. Your only option is - external connection.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2/1/18 ACI does not support VNets yet, however this is at the top of our backlog as we are aware of the need to place instances within a VNet. We are actively working on this and it is coming soon.